# R using melt() and dcast() with categorical and numerical variables at the same time

Tags: r, melt, dcast

I am a newbie in programming with R, and this is my first question ever here on Stackoverflow.

Let's say that I have a data frame with 4 columns: 
(1) Individual ID (numeric); 
(2) Morality of the individual (factor); 
(3) The city (factor); 
(4) Numbers of books possessed (numeric).

```
Person_ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
Morality <- c("Bad guy","Bad guy","Bad guy","Bad guy","Bad guy",
          "Good guy","Good guy","Good guy","Good guy","Good guy") 
City <- c("NiceCity", "UglyCity", "NiceCity", "UglyCity", "NiceCity", 
         "UglyCity", "NiceCity", "UglyCity", "NiceCity", "UglyCity") 
Books <- c(0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27)
mydf <- data.frame(Person_ID, City, Morality, Books)
```

I am using this code in order to get the counts by each category for the variable `Morality` in each city:

```
mycounts<-melt(mydf,
               idvars = c("City"),
               measure.vars = c("Morality"))%>%
  dcast(City~variable+value,
        value.var="value",fill=0,fun.aggregate=length)
```

The code gives this kind of table with the sums:

```
names(mycounts)<-gsub("Morality_","",names(mycounts))
mycounts
      City Bad guy Good guy
1 NiceCity       3        2
2 UglyCity       2        3
```

I wonder if there is a similar way to use `dcast()` for *numerical* variables (**inside the same script**) e.g. in order to get a sum the `Books` possessed by all individuals living in each city:

`#>       City   Bad guy     Good guy        Books`  
`#>1 NiceCity       3            2         [Total number of books in NiceCity]`  
`#>2 UglyCity       2            3         [Total number of books in UglyCity]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```r
mydf %>% 
  melt(
    idvars = c("City"),
    measure.vars = c("Morality")
  ) %>%
  dcast(
    City ~ variable + value,
    value.var = "Books", 
    fill = 0,
    fun.aggregate = sum
  )
#>       City Morality_Bad guy Morality_Good guy
#> 1 NiceCity               18                42
#> 2 UglyCity               12                63
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. 
That was not my question, though. I apologize if I wasn't clear enough. 
I would like to get a table with two columns with the counts for each category of the categorical variable `Morality` and a third column showing the sum for the numerical variable `Books`, in each city.

Comment: `missing_column <- aggregate(Books ~ City, mydf, sum)` , this calculates the total `Books` by city. Yet, if I add this code (`%>%`) e.g. to your code, it won't work.